# using VS Code to debug Chrome，but web request keeps pending

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, debugging, web, chrome-canary

I'm using VS Code to debug Chrome. When I set a breakpoint in VS Code and refresh the page, the page doesn't load and the request keeps pending. I noticed that if I don't refresh the page, the breakpoint debugging works fine. What could be causing this issue?"

It seems that the .map requests in the VS Code terminal are not being properly proxied by the .pac rules. I am using a .pac proxy to debug my local application using the domain name.

Comment: Same problem here. When I tried debugging with Microsoft Edge, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your chrome debugger is not deprecated. Install chrome debugger in the extensions tab.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome Debugger is deprecated like Jay Hyber is saying.

You'll find `[Deprecated] Debugger for Chrome` in VS Code Extensions.

Since Visual Studio offers the same functionalities with the `JavaScript Debugger` (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug) it is deprecated and can cause problemes.

Thats what [Deprecated] Debugger for Chrome suggests:

> This extension has been deprecated as Visual Studio Code now has a bundled JavaScript Debugger that covers the same functionality. It is a debugger that debugs Node.js, Chrome, Edge, WebView2, VS Code extensions, and more. You can safely un-install this extension and you will still be able to have the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using @neneil comment as a reference, I've tried the extension's nightly version and it worked. No more pending connection in debug session with breakpoints active. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly

@user20134561, could you try and give us some feedback if it worked.